# Spark not executing tasks

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark

I cant get the pyspark to work. I added the necessary paths to the system variable `SPARK_HOME`. I extracted data from my mongodb database and simply converted the obtained list to dataframe. Then, I want to see the dataframe through `show()` (the last line of code) which gives the following error. My hadoop version is 2.7, pyspark and local spark both are 2.4.1, python 3.6. Java version is 8.

```
import os
import sys
spark_path = r"C:\Tools\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7" # spark installed folder
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = spark_path
sys.path.insert(0, spark_path + "/bin")
sys.path.insert(0, spark_path + "/python/pyspark/")
sys.path.insert(0, spark_path + "/python/lib/pyspark.zip")
sys.path.insert(0, spark_path + "/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip")

import pymongo
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pandas as pd
import pyspark
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re as re
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer , IDF
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vector, Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import LDA, LDAModel
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

sc = SparkContext(appName = "app")
# print(sc.version)

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["The_Rival_Insights"]
mycol = mydb["twitter"]

def getText(keyword):
    myquery = {'keyword': keyword}
    for x in mycol.find(myquery):     #x is a dictionary
        a=x["metadata"]
        return a

text=[]
metadata = getText("uber")    #list is returned
for b in range(len(metadata)):
    text.append(str(metadata[b]["text"]))
data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(text,StringType()).show()
```

The following error occurs:

```
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]2019-04-07 17:50:08 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-04-07 17:50:08 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2019-04-07 17:50:08 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mujtaba Faizi/Documents/Twitter-Sentiment-Analysis-Using-Spark-Streaming-And-Kafka-master/Analysis/sparkml_testing.py", line 41, in <module>
    data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(text,StringType()).show()
  File "F:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 378, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "F:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "F:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "F:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1887)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1875)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1874)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1874)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2108)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2057)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2046)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3384)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2759)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more

SUCCESS: The process with PID 152396 (child process of PID 151964) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 151964 (child process of PID 151992) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 151992 (child process of PID 151592) has been terminated.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also, I get another error when I add the code in the end (whilst removing the `show()` function):

```
reviews = data.rdd.map(lambda x : x[0]).filter(lambda x: x is not None)
StopWords = stopwords.words("english")
tokens = reviews                                                   \
    .map( lambda document: document.strip().lower())               \
    .map( lambda document: re.split(" ", document))          \
    .map( lambda word: [x for x in word if x.isalpha()])           \
    .map( lambda word: [x for x in word if len(x) > 3] )           \
    .map( lambda word: [x for x in word if x not in StopWords])    \
    .zipWithIndex()
```

Clipped Error Messages:

```
    Setting default log level to "WARN".
    To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
    [Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 4) / 4]2019-04-07 19:04:30 ERROR PythonRunner:91 - Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Tools\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 267, in main
    Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:588)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:578)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37
        at 
org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)
    2019-04-07 19:04:30 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:578)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:153)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:557)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)
    2019-04-07 19:04:30 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:578)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:153)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:557)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)

    2019-04-07 19:04:30 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 2 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Mujtaba Faizi/Documents/Twitter-Sentiment-Analysis-Using-Spark-Streaming-And-Kafka-master/Analysis/sparkml_testing.py", line 52, in <module>
        .map( lambda word: [x for x in word if x not in StopWords])    \
      File "F:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2174, in zipWithIndex
        nums = self.mapPartitions(lambda it: [sum(1 for i in it)]).collect()
      File "F:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 816, in collect
        sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
      File "F:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
        answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
      File "F:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
        return f(*a, **kw)
      File "F:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
        format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Answer (score 1):

*If somebody stumbled on this like me and is working on a cluster but with the need to run some local scripts on a target node*.

---

**SOLUTION**

The easiest foolproof solution would be setting PYSPARK_PYTHON env at the beginning of the script, since in my case pyspark-shell could not pick it up even if configured properly in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` or even in `spark-defaults.conf` and `~/.bashrc` (both less desirable than the first option).

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = '/path/to/python3' # Worker executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = '/path/to/python3' # Driver executable
```

---

**PROBABLE CAUSE**

I am not entirely sure, but my guess is pyspark installed from pip in your venv is different than the one that is actually loaded by Spark itself and it doesn't find the correct env variable, resorting to the default python 2.7 executables despite configuring it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not use Pymongo. MongoDB has a Spark connector which can be made available via the `--packages` option in spark-submit.

If you are using a remote MongoDB cluster, you need to whitelist your IP in the Network where MongoDB resides. This is one if the reason the Error message **Connection Reset** is encountered and I have faced it too.

[Spark-MongoDB connector Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python-api/) follow this link and you'd be able to work on Spark DFs directly.

**UPDATE**

After going through your stack-trace (apologies for not reading it thoroughly), it seems your worker nodes do not have Python 3 installed on them. You need to install the correct version of Python which matches the one installed on your driver node. Then on each worker node you need to add the following line `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/to/python3/executable` in your `.bash_profile` file located in your users' home directory. It should solve your issue.