# How to correctly set python version in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My spark version is 2.4.0, it has python2.7 and python 3.7 . The default version is python2.7. Now I want to submit a pyspark program which uses python3.7. I tried two ways, but both of them don't work.

1. ```
   spark2-submit --master yarn \ 
   --conf "spark.pyspark.python=/usr/bin/python3" \
   --conf "spark.pyspark.driver.python=/usr/bin/python3"   pi.py
   ```

   It doesn't work and says

   ```
   Cannot run program "/usr/bin/python3": error=13, Permission denied
   ```

   But actually, I have the permission, for example, I can use 
   `/usr/bin/python3 test.py` 
   to run a python program.
2. ```
   export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
   export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
   ```

   In this way, spark can't use python3 at all.

Comment: where are you adding the exports? you should put them in spark-env.sh and reboot the cluster. Also you can "cheat" and put them in your .py main file as reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56851638/4679992

Comment: I already tried the way which  mentioned in your link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559763/spark-not-executing-tasks/56851638#56851638), but it still doesn't work, and says "Cannot run program "/usr/bin/python3": error=13, Permission denied"

Comment: Are you sure you have the permission? The user who actually runs the .py file might be different than the user who runs the original spark-submit cmd. Did you check if you have any --proxy-user setting somewhere? It might help if you add yourself as a superuser on the yarn side of things. Look here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Superusers.html

Comment: The above is valid only if you run Spark-on-Yarn of course.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I found that including the spark location in the python script tends to be much easier, for this use `findspark`.

```
import findspark
spark_location='/opt/spark-2.4.3/' # Set your own
findspark.init(spark_home=spark_location)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

Solution of configuring the env in the beginning of the script (in [Spark not executing tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559763/spark-not-executing-tasks/56851638#56851638)) did not work for me.

Without restarting the cluster, just executing the command below worked for me.

```
sudo sed -i -e '$a\export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3' /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
```