# ImportError: No module named configparser on Pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

While submitting a job on spark cluster, I am getting an error as

```
ImportError: No module named configparser
```

Point to note here is while developing the pyspark application in m y pycharm, I did not exclusively added configparser from pip or any other package. It was present by default. But when I submit the job on cluster which also runs on Python 3, I get this error in the import line.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

The library is a part of the standard library and should generally be available on PySpark. However the question is: are you *indeed* using Python 3? In Python 2, the module was called `ConfigParser`; PySpark using Python 2 might explain the reason. Try `import ConfigParser` or check what `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` outputs.

Comment: Interesting. I got the output as sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0). Does this mean, the version of pyspark in my cluster is 2.7.5 ?

Comment: @earl that's a bingo

Comment: How do I import PYTHONPATH in my py file? I am using SparkSession

Comment: Tried options like sys.path.index('/opt/test/python37/bin'); os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/opt/test/python37/bin' but they are not able to over ride the PYTHONPATH which is set as default

Comment: @earl that is another question, and it has an answer already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57953227/how-to-correctly-set-python-version-in-spark

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience, to solve this problem you need to correctly set the python version [How to correctly set python version in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57953227/how-to-correctly-set-python-version-in-spark).